# Remove some values from collection of collections using java streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Imagine a collection of collections(set of sets):

```
    Set<Set<Long>> setOfSets = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(4L);
    set.add(3L);
    set.add(8L);
    setOfSets.add(set);
    set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(6L);
    set.add(7L);
    set.add(4L);
    setOfSets.add(set);
```

How do I remove given value from this collection using java streams? For example if the given value is 4 then expected sets should be equal to {[3, 8][6, 7]}. I know that this is possible with iterating through the collection(s) using nested for loops, but I'm specifically interested in using streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<Set<Long>> result = setOfSets.stream()
                                 .map(s -> s.stream()
                                            .filter(id -> (id != 4L))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they're pass-by-reference, you can just mutate them directly:

```
int removeNum = 4;
setOfSets.forEach(s -> s.remove(removeNum));

//add it to each
setOfSets.forEach(s -> s.add(removeNum));
```

While it isn't *technically* a stream solution, it's pretty much along those lines.